# What redstone circuit will turn a short pulse into a single very long pulse?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Specifically, I’ll be taking an input from a tripwire, and my desired output is that a pulse generator runs for thirty seconds or so and then stops. My first thought is AND gate a generator to a single thirty second  pulse to get the output I’m looking for.  I would like a design that fits into a 20x20 area if possible.

Comment: Signal lengthener. The kind you want usually uses comparators. Google helps until I have the time for a proper answer.

Comment: Do any of these pulse extenders work? https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Redstone_circuits/Pulse/pulse_extender